# Select element in webpage using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to select these fields in a webpage using Selenium in FireFox. The HTML page is like 
[Sample HTML Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP3ot.jpg),
[another sample page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oerhQ.jpg)

I used following code :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("list_item-2221889")).click();
```

I am passing the id's of the a-tag but that is not working. Does anyone know any better way to select those a-tags ?

The exception I am getting is as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #list_item\-2221889
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'somePc', ip: '10.8.0.206', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.dYp9vdWr9LgT, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=14524.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: f9bf7f0c-5f8c-4dce-a41c-0cf86c8f5420
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=list_item-2221889}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:453)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
```

Comment: What kind of error or exception is thrown? Can you add this to you question?

Comment: I need to select certain portion of element like this:

<a href="javascript:showStackTrace(2221889);" class="list-group-item" id="list_item-2221889">
</a>

Comment: Can you refresh page and check if `id` value changed? If so, try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id, 'list_item-')]")).click();`

Comment: @Andersson : No the id does not change when I refresh the page.

Comment: try with  `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.row div.col-md-4 ul.list-group a")).click();`

Comment: @garryOldMan After going through your Question if none of the Answers provided have worked for you, I suppose there are multiple tables on the Webpage of your interest. In that case I would like to see a bit more (than you provided as attachment) of your HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: @Dev I have edited the question with second sample image. I need to select few of the a-tags which differ by their id.

Comment: @garryOldMan Observe the yesterday's HTML DOM you attached. The `id` of the very first element was `list_item-2221889` and observe today's HTML DOM you attached. The `id` of the very first element today is `list_item-2276632`. So can you confirm if the `id` of the elements are getting changed dynamically?

Comment: @Dev No the id's are not changing dynamically. I just happened to screenshot another such page. I am providing the correct ids when I try.

Comment: @garryOldMan If you don't provide us the correct info how can we help you :) I need to see the pattern of the `id` of those elements which you want to select. Thanks

Comment: @garryOldMan Open the console in the browser and type $x("a[@id='list_item-2221889']") and tell us if it returns something or not

Comment: @mosaad It's returning empty array , does this mean that the id does not exist or is there any way to select those a-tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wait some time until element appears in `DOM` and became clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#list_item-2221889"))).click();
```

If you get `TimeOut` exception, check whether target link located inside an `iframe`. If so, you need to switch to `iframe` before handling link:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeNameOrId");
driver.findElement(By.id("list_item-2221889")).click();
```

Comment: If you get `TimeOut`, then most likely your element located inside `<iframe>`. Check ancestors of link

Answer (score 0):

```
var aTags = driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[@class='list-group-item']"));

foreach(var aTag in aTags)
{
aTag.click();
}
```

You can click all a-tags with this method. If you want to only first a-tag click, use;

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//a[@class='list-group-item'][1]")).click();
```

(language is C#, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is to use xpath and locate the element.

For example if you need to click the first element in the list,

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//ul[@class='list-group']/a[1]).click();
```

and for second element and so on

```
 driver.findElement(By.xPath("//ul[@class='list-group']/a[2]).click();
```

Use explicit wait if the table takes time to load. Try this and let me know.
Thanks.